# Отправка https-запроса и получение данных

Tags: java, https

Делаю java-приложение, которое работает с WarGaming Public API.

Как послать https-запрос, а потом вывести ответ сервера в консоль?

Comment: с помощью AJAX Вы можете присылать и отправлять сообщение. В каком формате будет приниматься сообщение?

Comment: Тут есть пример ответа сервера: https://ru.wargaming.net/developers/api_explorer/wot/account/info/?application_id=demo&account_id=392504&http_method=GET&run=1

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// HTTP GET request
private void sendGet() throws Exception {

    String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=mkyong";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}
```

Источник [тут](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас проверю.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) построенный на apache http api.

```
String uri = "http://www.google.com/search?q=mkyong";
HttpRequest<String> httpRequest = HttpRequestBuilder.createGet(uri, String.class)
.addDefaultHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT)
.responseDeserializer(ResponseDeserializer.ignorableDeserializer()).build();

public void send(){
  ResponseHandler<String> response = httpRequest.execute();
  System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
  System.out.println(response.get()); //retuns response body
}
```